# Continue to run a SQL query after the connection closes

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, is it possible to call a long-running stored procedure, close the connection and let it finish? I don't care about the result. Essentially I want to say "Hey SQL, do this work on your own server."

I want to avoid having to make some service to sit with the open connection and wait for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a SQL Agent job to run the procedure that has no schedule, then issue a SQL command to start the job with "EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = ''"  If you have to change the command frequently it may not be ideal, but that can be done through SQL calls if needed.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that. A job can't take inputs though. I was thinking of having a table for that. The web request might call a stored proc that stores the inputs somewhere, starts the job and returns. That might be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `BeginExecuteNonQuery(AsyncCallback, Object)`, and then have a callback method that effectively does nothing. It's worth mentioning that the connection won't actually be *closed*, however.

[MSDN SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b6f9k7k.aspx)

Alternatively, you could use Service Broker to queue the request to run a stored procedure. There's a fair bit of plumbing to set up, though. It might not be worth it in your situation. Especially if you aren't using Service Broker for anything else. The advantage here is that the connection can be closed immediately after queuing with Service Broker, and placing messages into a queue is a very quick operation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Ideally I'd like to initiate it from an ASP.NET web application. During a web request, it'd ask SQL to begin an operation, then end the web request. It'd be bad form, I guess, to orphan the connection or callback in some IIS worker process. :p I'll read about Broker Service.